# How do you use SetTabBehaviour in wxWidgets for C++?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxgrid

I'm new to C++ Widgets and am trying to use the wxWidgets to create a grid. 
I have come across the function: "SetTabBehaviour" in the following documentations: (https://fossies.org/linux/wxWidgets/include/wx/generic/grid.h) and (https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html#acd42a9c04692a5ef6b0a4997c4e9a77e). 
How does one go about calling this class? Any help would be greatly appreciated, including help on calling enums or classes in C++.

Comment: To try to give you an answer: you create a `wxGrid` instance and call `SetTabBehaviour()` function passing it one of the `enum` values.

However, you really need to understand C++ before using it for programming. If you ask this kind of questions the answer above is truly not enough. This "question" should actually be closed.

Comment: Thank you, but that is what I have been doing. The issue is that the compiler says " error: 'Tab_Wrap' was not declared in this scope" and so I was wondering if there was an import class I was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tab_XXX` constants are declared inside `wxGrid` class, so you need to qualify them with `wxGrid::` prefix when using them, e.g. `grid->SetTabBehaviour(wxGrid::Tab_Stop)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped tremendously in both understanding more on the C++ language and in this particular problem. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you ! I had the same problem